# Javascript scope inside Backbone object

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, backbone.js, scope

I am currently working on backbone single page app using google map and there is a scope issue that I have troubles understanding.
Basically all scripts are included in the right order but it seems that I can't instanciate a google map object outside in a global object property outside of a function.
here is the working ex of my view declaration:

```
Viewer.Views.PhotosMap = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('#conteneurLoad'),
markersOld: {},
mapOptions: function() {
    return {

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.3152208011549, -70.40635300000008),

    };
},...
```

the failing one:

```
Viewer.Views.PhotosMap = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('#conteneurLoad'),
markersOld: {},
mapOptions: {

    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.3152208011549, -70.40635300000008),

},...
```

I get a google is undefined in the second case.
Any clear explanation will help a lot
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok my bad, 
the (not so) obvious problem was in the fact that the first ex is executed only on function call and the second when parsing the file. Thus in this case the include order of the scripts matters.